# Discord.py Disable Button after Click

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have been having a problem on how to disable a discord.py button on click.
Running `button.disabled = True` in the callback didn't do anything.

I have tried:

```py
async def button_callback(interaction):
    interaction.response.send_message("You clicked me! Now I'm disabling this.")
    button1.disabled = True
button1.callback = button_callback
```

The code is in another function, which has the button button1 in it.

I expected the button to be disabled.
What happened was it just stayed the same. (No errors)

Note: I do not want to install other modules or make new classes. Thank you! (I want and ONLY use Discord.PY itself)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When making any changes to the components of a [View](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#view), you will need to update the message view for this change to take effect on the discord side. Also, I recommend that you create your views by inherited classes.
I'll show you an example of a view where the button is disabled after clicking:

```py
import discord


class MyView(discord.ui.View):
    
    @discord.ui.button(label="Click Here", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green)
    async def click_here(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.Button):
        # disabling the button
        button.disabled = True
        # assuming you sent the view along with an Embed
        emb = interation.message.embeds[0]
        emb.description = "You clicked me! Now I'm disabling this."
        # updating the message view and embed
        await interaction.response.edit_message(embed=emb, view=self)
```

To send this view, just use `view=MyView()` when responding to a command.

Comment: Is there any way that i can disable other buttons in one button press?
Example: if you press `b1`, it disables `b1`, `b2`, and `b3`
Thank you!

Comment: Yes. You can use [self.children](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.ui.View.children) to iterate over the view buttons.

Comment: A follow-up to the question:
I sent the embed in the parent function. How can I update it if it's not in the Class?
My embed: `discord.Embed(title="Press a Button", description="click one")`

Comment: You can get the embed using `interaction.message.embeds[0]`

Comment: I don't really understand how the code works. Can you give me an example? Thanks!
note: I have many embeds, not just one

Comment: Are you working with Webhoooks? A regular message can have only one embed

Comment: No. What I mean is there is one embed, and the embed's view is MyView(). I don't understand how to use `interaction.message.embeds[0]`. Is it like `interaction.message.embeds[0].edit_message(view=self)`? Thanks!

Comment: If you want to edit the embed, just add the parameter: `await interaction.response.edit_message(view=self, embed=my_embed)`.

Comment: I'm editing the answer showing how to edit the message embed description

Comment: Please read the documentation: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.InteractionResponse.edit_message

Comment: I have many embeds, in the function `send_embed`. Is there a way that I can edit the individual embed? At this point, I'll get other modules if needed. (sorry, I'm a new discord Bot dev)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by _many embed_. A message can have only one embed (unless if it is sent by a webhook).

Comment: Like, there's a `send_embed` function, and there is a embed in it. Since the bot is designed to handle more than 1 message, I cannot make it a global variable, only a function one. How should I reference the exact embed in the MyView class? Should. I make the embed a input in the class?

Comment: Yes, you can pass to the class the `Embed` you want to send.

Comment: I get this: `discord.app_commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command 'send_embed' raised an exception: AttributeError: 'MyView' object has no attribute '_children'` when I run `view = MyView(embed)`

Comment: Seems like you didn't inherit the class `discord.View`

Comment: If you want to add attributes to `MyView` you must do it by defining a `__init__()` method.

Comment: I did. I gave it `def __init__(self, embed)` then `self.embed = embed`.

Comment: Have you called `super().__init__()` in your `__init__` method of `MyView` ?